# .NET Client supporting multiple versions of an unmanaged DLL

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged, dll

I am developing a .NET 4.0 client that will utilize a C Library for data processing. The user will be able to specify the DLL file they wish to load for processing.

I am doing late binding / assembly loading as described here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx

For each DLL, the same method call sequences will be the same in my client, but the method signatures will change or the data structs passed in will change. The data populated with the structures will be different depending on the version of the DLL and other factors. Example, the definition of MyStruct will change depending on the version of the DLL.

`public delegate int INTF_my_method(ref MyStruct pDataStruct);`

What design patterns or design decision are recommended for this approach? I need to load the appropriate C method delegates and data definitions based on the version of the DLL that the user has specified, and populate the structures appropriately. Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clean approach to this, neither in managed code nor native code.  The best you could possibly do is to declare an interface type that tries to cover all possible versions and then write concrete wrapper classes for each individual version of the API.  If there's at least some common functionality then you can shovel that in a base class.

Notable too is that you cannot just let the user pick a DLL, you have to pair the DLL with the concrete wrapper class instance.

Building this kind of flexibility in your program is obviously *very* expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can load different versions of your DLLs, but only from separate AppDomains.  That is, for each DLL you want to load, you will have to create a new AppDomain.

Comment: if I want to have only 1 loaded at a time, I think I can use just 1 App Domain. Is that true?

Comment: Yes that's true, but in either case you still have the problem that Hans describes above, you will need some flexible wrapper classes.